# Setting Google Cloud Storage access-control-allow-origin header

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

As per Google's instructions, I create a cors-json-file.json

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 10
    }
]
```

Then apply it to my bucket

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://mybucket
```

Then a cURL request to get the headers

```
curl -H "Origin: https://example.com" -I https://mybucket.storage.googleapis.com/myfile.pdf
```

In the response, I see that my header has been set

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

But if instead I set the origin to something specific

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://example.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 10
    }
]
```

There is no **access-control-allow-origin** header in the cURL response!

(and my cross-origin attempts to read the file fail)

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `www.example.com` isn’t an origin. Instead do `"origin": ["https://www.example.com"]` or  `"origin": ["https://www.example.com"]`. That is, the origin value needs to include the `http` or `https` protocol part. And when you test with curl, do `curl -I -H "Origin: https://example.com" https://mybucket.storage.googleapis.com/myfile.pdf` or `curl -I -H "Origin: http://example.com" https://mybucket.storage.googleapis.com/myfile.pdf`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had already tried that too. I've updated my question, but unfortunately still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to have been a caching issue - a few days later and this is all working as expected.

Helpful suggestion from @sideshowbarker to check that you have used the full URL (including http://), and that also needs to be sent in request header in order to see the response header.

```
curl -H "Origin: https://example.com" -I https://mybucket.storage.googleapis.com/myfile.pdf
```

In the response, I now see that my header has been set:

```
access-control-allow-origin: http://example.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Put this in a json file:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["<THE URL FROM WHICH YOU ARE REQUESTING THE ASSET>"],
    "responseHeader": ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

and then run `gsutil cors set ./path/to/the/above/json  gs://your_bucket_name.appspot.com`

Comment: where do you add the json file?

Comment: @RobertTerrell Anywhere you want. You just have to specify the path to it in the command.